# How can I strip HTML tags from a string in the model before I get to the view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

Trying to determine how to strip the HTML tags from a string in Ruby. I need this to be done in the model before I get to the view. So using:

```
ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelperstrip_tags()
```

won't work. I was looking into using Nokogiri, but can't figure out how to do it.

If I have a string:

```
description = <a href="http://google.com">google</a>
```

I need it to be converted to plain text without including HTML tags so it would just come out as "google".

Right now I have the following which will take care of HTML entities:

```
def simple_description
  simple_description = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(self.description)
  simple_description.text
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call the sanitizer directly like this:

```
Rails::Html::FullSanitizer.new.sanitize('<b>bold</b>')
# => "bold"
```

There are also other sanitizer classes that may be useful: FullSanitizer, LinkSanitizer, Sanitizer, WhiteListSanitizer.

Comment: added it to my code getting the following error from rails:
`uninitialized constant Rails::HTML`

Comment: Just add `raw` helper before, so its looks like this `raw(Rails::Html::FullSanitizer.new.sanitize('<b>bold</b>'))` . It's work for me

Answer (score 1):

Nokogiri is a great choice if you don't own the HTML generator and you want to reduce your maintenance load:

```
require 'nokogiri'
description = '<a href="http://google.com">google</a>'
Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(description).at('a').text
# => "google"
```

The good thing about a parser vs. using patterns, is the parser continues work with changes to the tags or format of the document, whereas patterns get tripped up by those things.

While using a parser is a little slower, it more than makes up for that by the ease of use and reduced maintenance.

The code above breaks down to:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(description).to_html
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body><a href=\"http://google.com\">google</a></body></html>\n"
```

Rather than let Nokogiri add the normal HTML headers, I told it to parse only that one node into a document fragment:

```
Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(description).to_html
# => "<a href=\"http://google.com\">google</a>"
```

`at` finds the first occurrence of that node:

```
Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(description).at('a').to_html
# => "<a href=\"http://google.com\">google</a>"
```

`text` finds the text in the node.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could use regular expression in ruby like following

```
des = '<a href="http://google.com">google</a>'
p des[/<.*>(.*)\<\/.*>/,1]
```

The result will be "google"

Regular expression is powerful.

You could customize to fit your needs.

Comment: [Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?lq=1). That trick never works for anything resembling real world HTML. The question linked to covers why and why not, and is one of the most popular questions on the site. Consider your pattern's behavior if the text contained `>`.